# Xcode : Retrieving the Product Name from a target in command line

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

Is there a way to get the Product Name from a target in command line ?

I tried with `xcodebuild -list -project Foo.xcodeproj` but it lists only the targets.

Is there something like `xcodetargetinfo -target=foobar` that returns all the info related to the target including the product name ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is: `-showBuildSettings` switch. Usage:

```
xcodebuild -target <target> -configuration <configuration> -showBuildSettings  | grep -i 'PRODUCT_NAME'
```

You need to parse output manually.